# A question about removing equality in predicate logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm currently taking a course on Mathematical Modelling, more specifically Advanced Predicate Logic, and we were talking about predicate logic when I was introduced to these 2 rules:
$$\frac{}{t = t}[=i]\qquad\frac{t_1=t_2\quad[x\Rightarrow t_1]\phi}{[x\Rightarrow t_2]\phi}[=e]$$

Then, when we went to apply it to prove
$$f(x) = g(x)\vdash h(g(x)) = h(f(x)),$$ we were given a solution that looked like this:
\begin{align*}
1.\quad &f(x) = g(x)\qquad&\text{premise}\\
2.\quad &h(f(x)) = h(f(x))\qquad&=i\\
3.\quad &h(g(x)) = h(f(x))\qquad&=e\ 1,2
\end{align*}

I want to ask about the third line of the solution, specifically how ${=e}$ can be used with lines 1 & 2 to create line 3.

For context, the professor who gave this assignment gave an answer that went something like this:

${f(x) = g(x)}$ because of the premise.

Let ${\phi}$ be ${h(y) = h(y)}$ for all $y$, then $h(f(x)) = h(f(x))$ is from substituing $y = f(x)$ into $\phi$. (i.e. $[y\Rightarrow f(x)]\phi$).

From the first two lines, we can see that $[y\Rightarrow g(x)]\phi$, but we only need to substitute 1 side of $\phi$, leaving us with $h(g(x))=h(f(x))$.

We haven't learned about anything relating to ${\forall}$ & ${\exists}$ yet so don't worry about ${h(y) = h(y)}$ for all $y$.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please transcribe the problem and solution; do not use images, given you clearly have a handle on mathjax.  The easier you make it for users to answer, with having to open two links in additional tabs, the more successful you'll be on this site.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your feedback. I haven't known much about Latex so I could only write that much. I wished I could embed pictures in my questions, but I haven't had enough reputation point to do so. Besides, I don't think clicking a link would bother the answering process by that much. But I'll try to keep what you said in mind for when I ask other questions.

Comment: It does create a lot of bother; if your links break and the information is not in the question, nobody can later figure out what you meant to say with them. And that's presuming anybody trusts you enough to follow the links at all; I certainly don't, from a user without established reputation (in both senses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $t_1 := f(x)$, $t_2 := g(x)$, and put $\phi$ as $h(y) = h(f(x))$, then rule $[=e]$ says
$$\frac{f(x) = g(x)\quad h(f(x))=h(f(x))}{h(g(x))=h(f(x))}$$